# Colour dialog box

Tags: photoshop-script

Is it possible mid script, to open up the colour picker dialogue box in Photoshop, for the user to pick a colour, and then carry on with the script? Scriptlistener doesn't find anything.

```
app.showColorPicker()
```

and

```
$.colorPicker(ColorPicker.ADOBE);
```

Don't work for me in cs2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var color=app.showColorPicker()
var foregroundColor = app.foregroundColor;  
alert ("foregroundcolor\n"+foregroundColor.rgb.red+"\n"+foregroundColor.rgb.green+"\n"+foregroundColor.rgb.blue);
```

And you will see this:

[image]

and get this:

[image]

Unfortunately, you will need **Photoshop CS5 or better** :-(

**Alternative Idea**

I am not sure when `app.system()` was introduced into Photoshop, but if you have that it *shells out* to execute the command you provide as a parameter. So, you could go into OSX's *Script Editor* and type in

```
choose color
```

and save that as an application called `OSXColorPicker`. Then in Photoshop, you could do

```
app.system("open OSXColorPicker");
```

Comment: That is true.  Sadly, app.showColorPicker() is not a function in prehistoric times. we have dinosaurs though ;)

Comment: Are you Windows or Mac OS X?

Comment: I'm running on Win XP (someone has to)